# getting png image from context but view color changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, png

hi all i am using below code to get png formated image from the context and saving into particular path.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.2);
for(id rects in textRects){

    CGRect rect = [rects CGRectValue];
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect); 
}
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
textImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(textImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"folder"];


[imageData writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/subfolder/assets/0.png"] atomically:YES];

 }
```

here my problem is after getting the image from the above code my view color is changing from normally available color(which is before creating png) to entirely black color can any one give me the exact reason why it is happening
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `imageData` is valid before writing to file

Comment: yes thats way it is appearing in the path

Answer (score 1):

See 4 line of code getting png image from Context.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks

Comment: @AAAAAAAAA: Check to put comment on CGContextSetRGBFillColor function